# Why does this function with "this" not work? About "this" and its scope

Tags: javascript, scope, this

I know that adding a method to the prototype this way is not the best, but I'm just  testing.

```js
Array.prototype.maap = function (transform) {
  let mapped = [];
  for (let element of this) {
        mapped.push(transform(element));
  }
  return mapped;
}

console.log([0, 2, 3].maap(n => n / this.length));
```

I am getting:

[NaN, Infinity, Infinity]. I think the problem is "this.length".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, the problem is `this.length`. The trouble is that it's *not in the function*! It's in a lambda, whose scope is not that of the array by which it's later invoked. As such, `this` is not the array, and `this.length` is a solid 0 (0/0 being NaN, 2/0 being infinity and 3/0 also being infinity).

You can either hardcode the real value `3`, or move your logic into the function itself. Or you could have the lambda (actually an "arrow function" in JavaScript) take another parameter: that of the denominator.

```js
Array.prototype.maap = function (transform) {
  let mapped = [];
  for (let element of this) {
        mapped.push(transform(element, this.length));
  }
  return mapped;
}

console.log([0, 2, 3].maap((n, m) => n / m));
```

Comment: Thanks. When I console.log'd the "this" I did notice it was "window" but didn't get why. I thought that it would take maap's this, which is the array, because, according to the eloquent javascript book, "Arrow functions are different—they do not bind their own this but can see the this binding of the scope around them". I thought the maap function qualified as "the scope around" it.

Comment: @SRCP But the arrow function isn't in the maap function. It's passed _to_ the maap function. It's just an expression used as a function argument, in code at global scope.

Comment: Ah, I see. It being a function confused me. In the end, it just returns a value, which is the argument. Got it.

Comment: @SRCP: Kinda, yeah. It's better to think that it _is_ the argument. It doesn't really return a value, and it's not a function that's invoked there. It _is_ a function. It's a bit more like if you literally just wrote `console.log([0,2,3].maap(nameOfAFunctionThatAlreadyExists)`. In fact that's exactly what it's like.

Answer (score 1):

`this` inside an arrow function references the same `this` in its containing block. Here, the containing block is the top level, where `this` refers to `window`, and `window.length` is `0`.

```js
console.log(this === window);
console.log(window.length);
```

So, your code is equivalent to:

```js
Array.prototype.maap = function(transform) {
  let mapped = [];
  for (let element of this) {
    mapped.push(transform(element));
  }
  return mapped;
}

console.log(this.length);
console.log([0, 2, 3].maap(n => n / 0));
```

`0 / 0` is `undefined`, while most any other number `/ 0` is `Infinity` (or `-Infinity`).

If you want to emulate `Array.prototype.map`'s behavior with `this`, the second argument passed to `maap` should be the `this` value the callback is invoked with:

```js
Array.prototype.maap = function(transform, thisVal) {
  let mapped = [];
  for (let element of this) {
    mapped.push(transform.call(thisVal, element));
  }
  return mapped;
}

const arr = [0, 2, 3];
console.log(arr.maap(
  function(n){ return n / this.length; },
  arr
));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is on the arrow function (the param `transform`), Yes, `this.length` is the directly related questions, go deeper, it's a problem about [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions),

> An arrow function does not have its own `this`. The `this` value of the enclosing lexical scope is used;

Simply put， where the arrow function defined where the `this` point.

So, for your code, The parameters you passed in is `n => n / this.length`, and it is defined in function `console.log` in the environment of `window`. So the real problem is：

```
transf = (n) => {
  console.log(this);    // Window {postMessage: ƒ, blur: ƒ, focus: ƒ, close: ƒ, parent: Window, …}
  return n / this.length
}
console.log([0, 2, 3].maap(transf));
```